# Почему так сложно залить проект на github?

Tags: git, git-remote

Снова вылазят какие-то ошибки и предупреждения, типа следующего:

```
To https://github.com/NameUser/NameProject
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to     'https://github.com/NameUser/NameProject'
подсказка: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
подсказка: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
подсказка: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
подсказка: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Это после того, как я вручную на сервере удалил несколько файлов. Ладно. Делаю pull:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 1069, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (1069/1069), 1.08 MiB | 4.00 KiB/s, done.
remote: Total 1069 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1063
Resolving deltas: 100% (630/630), done.
From https://github.com/NameUser/NameProject
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    buildozer.spec
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Жалуется, мол, есть несинхронизированные изменения. Файл buildozer.spec давно выпилен из проекта и не отслеживается. Почему все так сложно с этими системами контроля версий?

Comment: Как будто без систем контроля версий всё просто. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
error: failed to push some refs to     'https://github.com/NameUser/NameProject'
подсказка: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
подсказка: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
подсказка: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
подсказка: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Тут все совершенно естественно. На сервере появились новые коммиты. Вы должны их забрать перед push-ем.

Далее.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    buildozer.spec
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
```

У вас в локальной рабочей директории есть неотслеживаемый файл `buildozer.spec`. Но на сервере он еще отслеживаемый. Git во время pull-а пытается обновить его состояние. Но т.к. в вашем локальном репозитории этот файл уже не отслеживается, git не имеет права делать с ним merge. Просто удалите его. Или, если он вам нужен, переименуйте, проведите pull, переименуйте обратно.

Comment: _Вы должны их забрать перед push-ем._ - а как же какой-нибудь принудительный пуш?:)

Comment: На сервере нет файла buildozer.spec, так я его удалил, поэтому pullom забрать я его не могу. А push, как видите, не проходит.

Comment: @Xyanight он не на сервере, он **у вас на компьютере**. Удалите, если он вам не нужен, гит за это не отвечает.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, вы очень помогли!